# Show that $n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}$ is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, induction

How can one show that $n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}$ is increasing, possibly using logarithms but not derivatives?  I obtain $(n^2+2n)log(n+1)\geq (n^2+2n+1)log (n)$ but cannot proceed further.

Answer (score 15):

*A purely algebraic proof*

We have to prove that
$$\bigl(n+1\bigr)^{\tfrac{n+2}{n+1}}> n^{\tfrac{n+1}{n}}\iff (n+1)^{n(n+2)}>n^{(n+1)^2}.$$
Note that $\;(n+1)^{n(n+2)}=(n+1)^{(n+1)^2-1} $, so the last inequality is equivalent to
$$\frac{(n+1)^{(n+1)^2-1}}{n^{(n+1)^2}}>1\iff\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)^{(n+1)^2}>n+1$$
Let's apply *Bernoulli's inequality*:
$$\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)^{(n+1)^2}>1+\frac{(n+1)^2}{n}=1+n+2+\frac 1n>3+n.$$

Comment: Well done!  (+1)

Comment: (+1) I wrote an answer, but when I simplified it, it became very similar to yours.

Comment: @robjohn: Great minds think together! ;o)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** : Use the fact that $\ln(n+1) \geq \ln(n) +\frac{1}{n+1}$

Lemma : $\ln(n+1) \geq \ln(n)+\frac{1}{n+1}$

Or we have $\ln(\frac{n+1}{n}) \geq \frac{1}{n+1}$

Exponent-ate both side gives us that $1+\frac{1}{n} =1+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\cdots\geq e^{\frac{1}{n+1}} = 1+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{2(n+1)^2}+\cdots$

Visually the proof is obvious.

Comment: How do I prove that?

Comment: you want a complete proof ?!

Comment: I simply cannot find a simple proof for my question, which seems very simple.

Comment: I would rather not rely on theorems proved later in real analysis.   I merely wish to use this fact as an intermediate result in a proof.

Comment: @HBHSU How do you define $\ln(x)$ and $e^x$ ?

Comment: I used the known summation of $e^x$ which is $\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ and $\ln n$ is the inverse function (Logarithm to the base $e$). @Surb

Comment: I am not sure how what Ahmad proved is used to prove my desired result.

Comment: @HBHSU The last inequality is true because the coefficient each term of the geometric series (on the LHS) is greater than the corresponding coefficient of the exponential series (on the RHS); more formally one can write $1+\frac1n-e^{1/(n+1)}$ as $\sum_{i=2}^\infty (1-\frac1{i!})(n+1)^{-i}$ and then note that every term in this sum is manifestly positive.

Comment: then you will have that $(n^2+2n)\ln(n+1) \geq (n^2+2n)(\ln n+\frac{1}{n+1}) \geq (n^2+2n+1) \ln n$ so you get to $\frac{n^2}{n+1}+n^2 \ln(n)+\frac{2 n}{n+1}+2 n \ln(n) \geq n^2 \ln(n)+2 n \ln(n)+\ln(n)$ , now don't tell me this is not clear.

Comment: @Ahmad I know this is the definition you are using and I think your proof is fine. It was more a rethoric question for HBHSU, as I expect that he would need "real analysis" to define $\ln$... (making his unsatisfaction on your proof somewhat meaningless).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Since $n^{1+1/n}=e^{(1+1/n)\ln{n}}$, and the exponential is a monotonically increasing function, so is $(1+1/n)\ln{n}$. Then verify that the function $g(x)=(1+1/x)\ln x$ is monotonically increasing.
One has only to prove that $g'(x)>0$ $\forall x>0$.
We have
\[
g'(x)= -\frac{1}{x^2}\ln x+\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\frac{1}{x}
\]
Then, using the inequality $-\ln x\geq 1-x$, valid for $x>0$, we obtain
\[
g'(x)\geq (1-x)\frac{1}{x^2}+\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\frac{1}{x}=\frac{2}{x^2}>0
\]

Answer (score 0):

Note (added after posting):  I didn't notice the OP's proscription on derivatives. I'm leaving the answer in case anyone wants to see an approach ignoring the proscription.

Let $u=1/n$.  Then

$$n^{n+1\over n}=n^{1+{1\over n}}=\left(1\over u\right)^{1+u}={1\over u^{1+u}}$$

It suffices to show that $u^{1+u}$ is an increasing function of $u$, which is equivalent to showing that $f(u)=(1+u)\ln u$ is an increasing function:

$$f'(u)={1+u\over u}+\ln u={1+u\over u}+\int_1^u{dt\over t}\ge{1+u\over u}+\int_1^u{dt\over u}={1+u\over u}+{u-1\over u}=2\gt0$$

Remark:  The inequality

$$\int_1^u{dt\over t}\ge\int_1^u{dt\over u}$$

is easy to see for $u\ge1$, since $1/t$ is being replaced by its smallest value, $1/u$.  For $0\lt u\lt1$ it's a bit trickier:  You're replacing $1/t$ with its *largest* value, but you're integrating "backwards," producing a negative number.